# Ubuntu one: u1conflict

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 and using Ubuntu One to sync my docs. I have about 500 `.doc` files, and I edit them constantly. I'm having problems with the appearance of `.u1conflict` files.

I have only one computer synced. **Please edit the following, it's incomprehensible**:
Has somehow to sync just on bootup/shudown to solve it?

Comment: @con-f-use In regards to the last part, I think they're asking if the problem could be solved by performing the sync only when booting and shutting down the system, but I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to hear that you're experiencing a misbehaviour in Ubuntu One.

You shouldn't have conflicts in Ubuntu One if you're using only one machine (and not touching the files through the web interface, of course). Currently we don't know about any bug about this situation if your system is fully updated (we had bugs about this).

If this is happening to you for files that previously were ok, we may have a bug that we don't know about! These kind of situations are very difficult to debug, so we normally ask for logs in TRACE mode.

So, the best way to continue with this and help us to find the reason of the problem you're experiencing is to put the logs in TRACE mode, and if this happens again, open a bug in the following URL and attach the logs there:

http://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+filebug

Here are instructions to put the log in TRACE mode:

1. stop the syncdaemon client ("u1sdtool --quit") and be sure it's fully stopped ("ps -eaf | grep ubuntuone-client" should give you nothing).
2. put a file named syncdaemon.conf  in your $HOME/.config/ubuntuone directory with the following information:

[logging]
level = TRACE

1. restart the client and keep it using it normally.

To collect the logs just zip your $HOME/.cache/ubuntuone/log/ folder.

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: That is not at all misbehavior. That is intended.

Answer (score 1):

.u1conflict files appear when the document you have on your local machine is not the same as the one you have in your personal cloud and not the one you're uploading. In that case, Ubuntu One doesn't know which is the correct version and therefore syncs all of them, but makes it obvious that there are conflicts. That way, you're never in danger of getting the wrong version.

You will often see this problem when you're using LibreOffice to edit documents that are stored in a synced folder. The reason is that LibreOffice saves automatically at certain intervals, while Ubuntu One tries to sync all changes. This means it's very easy for you to be in the process of uploading a document when the local document changes. It seems that LibreOffice saves the document even when no changes have been made, which makes the problem worse.

Because of this, I would not recommend that you work on such files directly in a synced folder, but instead have a working directory and copy your files when you need them synced. This is not as elegant as it should be, but I think it's the best way for now. Someone has proposed a plugin for LibreOffice that makes it work better with Ubuntu One, but I don't think any work has been started on that yet. In any case, we should've had a good GUI to show the conflicts and to fix them. Sadly, I don't think we have that yet either.

So, in summary, conflict files are good. They make sure you never loose any data, even if your internet connection suddenly become very slow, for instance.